# Images in ImageView with ratio 3:2

Tags: android, listview, imageview

There are many images that appear in the ListView.

My list_view_item.xml (image in ivEventImage):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivEventImage"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@null"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

They have different sizes - 640 x 480, 1280 x 720, 1920x1080, 1080x1920 and others. In addition to different sizes, different orientation - portrait or landscape.
And all images in different aspect ratio.

How to make the display of images in ImageView, BUT with an aspect ratio of 3:2 and if the image height not fit to show only the middle part of the image. But not to break ratio.

Black square - ivEventImage.
Left - 1280x720, right - 1080x1920 (for example).
[image: imageView problem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `centerCrop` instead of `fitXY` for `android:scaleType` as below...

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

So, `ImageView` xml will be...

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivEventImage"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@null"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```